# Find on 3 criteria basis and replace in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I want to find guid column in MySQL (Wordpress website) on 3 criteria. I searched in phpMyAdmin and exactly I find the results which I am looking for.

Unfortunately I cannot replace the selected guid from SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_posts` 
WHERE  `post_date` LIKE  '%2012-03%'
AND  `guid` NOT REGEXP  'http://www.'
AND  `post_type` =  'attachment'
REPLACE(guid,'http://', 'http://www.mydomain.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/')
```

The above replacement code is not working. What do I have to run in SQL (phpMyAdmin) to find from above 3 criteria?

```
(WHERE  `post_date` LIKE  '%2012-03%'
    AND  `guid` NOT REGEXP  'http://www.'
    AND  `post_type` =  'attachment')
```

and replace guid column from 'http://' to 'http://www.mydomain.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/'.

Answer (score 1):

Try update instead of replace

This site specifically changes urls in guids on word press
[Have a look](https://gist.github.com/wpsmith/6673714)

Comment: thanks , but i want to just update 2012 march attachment file..., please tell me how to find and replace on 3 criteria in mysql

Answer (score 0):

this is the perfect sql found in this webpage
http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1004440

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET guid = REPLACE(guid, 'http://', 'http://www.mydomain.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/')
WHERE  `post_date` LIKE  '%2012-03%'
AND  `guid` NOT REGEXP  'http://www.'
AND  `post_type` =  'attachment';
```